# failed to start elasticsearch on centos8

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using openjdk11 and centos8,   systemctl start elasticsearch.service as sudo user
got below error stack without any log, any idea? jvm size is set as Xmx512m Xms512m

```
[osboxes@ansible-controller ~]$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; ven>
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-03-11 12:01:26 EST; 6s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 3435 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.pidfi>
  Process: 3433 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd>
 Main PID: 3435 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 11 12:01:26 ansible-controller systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Mar 11 12:01:26 ansible-controller systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Mar 11 12:01:26 ansible-controller systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main proc>
Mar 11 12:01:26 ansible-controller systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed wi>
lines 1-12/12 (END)...skipping...
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-03-11 12:01:26 EST; 6s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 3435 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.pidfile=${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid -Des.default.path.home=${ES_HOME} -Des.default.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Des.defa>
  Process: 3433 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3435 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 11 12:01:26 ansible-controller systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Mar 11 12:01:26 ansible-controller systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Mar 11 12:01:26 ansible-controller systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 11 12:01:26 ansible-controller systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When i run ./elasticsearch --version , got below error, i read document
it said elasticsearch support openjdk11 already

```
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Java version I used is openjdk 11, also added at path already as below shown

```
[osboxes@ansible-controller bin]$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+1-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+1-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Same exit code suggests checking the Java Home directory: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-will-not-start-no-logs-code-exited-status-1-failure/135797/3

Comment: Or deleting i deleting /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/node.lock :https://discuss.elastic.co/t/failed-to-start-elasticsearch-code-exited-status-1-failure/217898/10